# UIActivityViewController sharing text + URL + Image on twitter (v7.33) not working on iOS 12

Tags: ios, twitter, uiactivityviewcontroller

I found an issue while sharing [text, url, image] on twitter, only text and image gets shared and not url. Sharing [text, url] or [text, image] works fine.

- Issue is not present if ios 11 and twitter 7.33 is used.
- Issue is not present if ios 12 and twitter 7.32.1 is used
- Issue occurs when ios 12 and the twitter (7.33) is used.

Code is as follows:

```
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: shareObjects, applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = constructExclusionArray(shareObjects)
    activityViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = activityViewControllerCompletionHandler
    rootViewController.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Is this an known issue?